# Failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 files: a Dockerfile to create the image and a docker-compose.yml for a small configuration. Both files are in the same directory. They look like these:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY target/CodeTechMedia-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "CodeTechMedia-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and

```
version: '3'
services:
  media-service:
    container_name: codetech-media
    build: /
    ports:
      - "8011:8081"
```

When I run docker-compose up, the Docker displays this:

```
Building media-service
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 60B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open \\?\E:\System Volume Information: Access is denied.
ERROR: Service 'media-service' failed to build : Build failed
```

The thing is it worked some days ago and today I decided to run the application again and ran into this. I feel somehow unable to understand what is going on with that access permission. I read about the `"buildkit": true` and I set it to `false` but ran into another problem so I stopped searching solutions and came directly with the problem.

Comment: `build: /` (pointing at the root directory) looks wrong; do you mean `build: .` (the current directory)?

Comment: @DavidMaze it worked! I don't know how this worked before with that / instead of dot. I was almost sure I knew what I was doing...